# How can I return the output as soon as the condition becomes true?

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        
        int i = 0;
        vector<int> arr = {};

        for(;i<nums.size();i++){
            int j = i + 1;
            for(;j<nums.size();j++){
                if((nums[i] + nums[j]) == target){
                        arr.push_back(i);
                        arr.push_back(j);
                        
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
      
    }
};
```

I want to return the arr as soon as the if condition becomes true , and the loops doesn't iterate ahead. I tried to use break but it only exits the loop for those values of i and j , and then continues for rest of the values for i.
How can I possibly do that?

Edit: Many users are saying to use return in if statement, which I had tried already, here is the error:

```
Compile Error
Line 20: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

1 error generated.

Comment: You can put `return` inside a loop, or you can experiment with [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) too.

Comment: I have already tried doing both of the above solutions , neither of them answers my problem

Comment: `return` inside `if` should definitely work. If it doesn't, edit your question your clarify what are the inputs that have issues, what is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior. Aside, don't `using namespace std`.

Comment: It would need to be `return arr;` (or return something else of type `vector<int>`) in the `if` block, not simply a naked `return;`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: where is the `using namespace`??

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm assuming that because of `vector` without `std`. Now to be fair, it is possible (but unlikely) that OP used `using std::vector` instead.

Comment: Solution is `O(n²)` whereas `O(n log n)` solution exists (and even, using `std::unordered_set` might make it `O(n)`).

Comment: Also note that competitive coding is NOT a good way to learn C++.

Comment: An alternative to `std::vector<int>` would be `std::optional<std::pair<int>>` in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  Do you mean `std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>`?

Comment: @Peter Yes, indeed :-)

Comment: For your edit, keep the original `return arr;` line in your question and also add the `return arr;` inside `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `return arr;` statement inside the `if` condition, *after* doing the `push_back` calls.
Also, keep the final `return arr;` statement, so that all control flows in the code will be returning the vector.

So the final function will appear like this:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        
        int i = 0;
        vector<int> arr = {};

        for(;i<nums.size();i++){
            int j = i + 1;
            for(;j<nums.size();j++){
                if((nums[i] + nums[j]) == target){
                        arr.push_back(i);
                        arr.push_back(j);
                        return arr; // What OP wants
                }
            }
        }
        return arr; // The compile error doesn't turn up
      
    }
};
```

Comment: The final `return` statement should be kept; don't get rid of it.